# Does any OS X hardware contain on chip h.264 encoding/decoding?

Tags: cpu, h.264, gpu

I know that iOS devices have the h.264 instruction set on chip, which helps to dramatically reduce processing (and thus, power, battery drain, etc.) when watching native video.

Has this been added to Intel CPUs, or ATI/nVidia GPUs, in Apple's Desktop/Laptop hardware?

Answer (score 1):

Apple's own apps on OSX has video acceleration support for years, provided by the GPU. h.264 hardware video acceleration is available to 3rd-party apps via the Video Decode Acceleration Framework since OSX 10.6.3. See:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2267/_index.html

http://arstechnica.com/apple/2008/10/digging-into-new-macbooks-support-of-gpu-accelerated-h-264/

http://xbmc.org/davilla/2010/05/03/osx-gets-h-264-accelleration/

Answer (score 0):

One of the Apple instructional videos from WWDC 2017 is exclusively on the subject of image and video compression. This video indicated h.265 is also now supported on some of the latest macOS hardware. THere's a table in that video and links to resource that say exactly what models support what resolutions and encodings/decodings.

Comment: Can you link to said video?

Comment: You can find it as fast as me I expect… was months since I watched it.

This is an intro to the graphics frameworks for all the OS: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/503/?time=2106

Click on the Transcript tab and you get text with links to other related videos in the last paragraph (force scroll to bottom of page). 

I'm not sure this is the video and don't have time to watch it all, sorry.